# Modify Asp.Net Core RazorViewEngineOptions at every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razorengine

My website has multiple themes, and each theme has different views which are stored in 
Themes/{theme-name}/Views Folder. 
When we update the theme in database the request pipeline should replace the razorviewengineoptions configured path with the selected theme's path which can be Themes/theme-name2/Views.
We are trying configure the RazorViewEngineOptions on controller by injecting IServiceCollection by setting it as singleton object in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs, After re-configuring the RazorViewEngineOptions on controller request by changing it to new path, the RazorViewEngineOptions are not updating and nothing happens.

```
Startup.cs: 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);

    string theme = Configuration[AppSetting.DefaultWebsiteTheme];

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(option =>
    {
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });
}

public DashboardController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration config, IServiceCollection services, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(unitOfWork, mapper)
{
    this.config = config;
    string theme = GetThemeSelected(unitOfWork);
    var razorviewengineOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>>();
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(option =>
    {
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        option.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        option.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Themes/" + theme + "/Views/Shard/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });
}
```